# Java: Convert String Date to Month Name Year (MMM yyyy)

Tags: java, date

I am new to Java. I am trying to convert date from string to MMM yyyy format (Mar 2016). I tried this

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy");
String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println("Month :: " + month_name);  //Mar 2016
```

It is working fine. But when I use

```
String actualDate = "2016-03-20";
```

It is not working. Help me, how to solve this.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. These basic date-time questions have been answered many times over.

Comment: If all you need is a year and month, consider using the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class. Passing and using objects of this class rather than strings gets you type-safety, valid values, and self-documenting code. Built into Java, so you can use throughout your code base. Can be formatted in the same manner as shown in the [correct Answer by Hajaj](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36113554/642706).

Comment: Whoops… I re-opened this Question thinking it was about parsing a year-month string which would *not* be a duplicate of the linked dup. But I misread this Question here, as it is about generating a year-month string from a year-month-date object. I should not have re-opened.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your format must match your input

for `2016-03-20`

the format should be (just use a second `SimpleDateFormat` object)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

---

### Full answer

```
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

String actualDate = "2016-03-20";

Date date = sdf.parse(actualDate);

String month_name = month_date.format(date);
System.out.println("Month :" + month_name);  //Mar 2016
```

---

Using `java.time` [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
String actualDate = "2016-03-20";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTimeFormatter dtf3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(actualDate, dtf);
String month_name = dtf2.format(ld);
System.out.println(month_name); // Mar 2016
String fullMonthAndYear = dtf3.format(ld);
System.out.println(fullMonthAndYear); // March 2016
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But how to convert  "2016-03-20"  to Mar 2016

Comment: @N123 first parse the string "2016-03-20" by formatter that uses "yyyy-MM-dd" pattern, then convert the result by formatter which uses "MMM yyyy"

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Thanks man . I added the answer

Comment: The input string complies with ISO 8601 standard, used by default in java.time. So no need to define a pattern. `LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2016-03-20" );`

Comment: @BasilBourque Its ok though. Important here is the logic

Comment: Agreed. Also, the `Locale` is optional in this particular case of parsing. But it is a wise habit to always specify the `Locale` explicitly, as shown here, rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default.

Comment: how to print full month name with year .. like this March-2016 instead of Mar-2016

Comment: Hello @MuddassirRahman, sorry I just see your question, use the pattern `MMMM-yyy` for your need

Answer (score 6):

Try this code:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM HH:mm a");
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
String infi = df.format(date);
```

And the output should be:

```
11-May 4:47 PM
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.from( 
    LocalDate.parse( "2016-03-20" )
) 
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( 
        "MMM uuuu" , 
        Locale.US 
    )
)
```

> Mar 2016

## java.time

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes. Entirely supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

## `YearMonth`

Java has a class to represent a year and month. Oddly named, `YearMonth`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2016-03-20" ) ;
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( ld ) ;
```

Define a formatting pattern for your desired output.

Specify a `Locale`. A [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) determines (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
String output = ym.format( f ) ;
```

> Mar 2016

You could use that formatter on the `LocalDate`. But I assume you may have further need of the year-month as a concept, and so the `YearMonth` class may be useful.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).